# mysql query optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

I would need some help on how to optimize the query.

```
select * from transaction where id < 7500001 order by id desc limit 16
```

when i do an explain plan on this - the type is "range" and rows is "7500000"
According to the some online reference's this is explained as, it took the query 7,500,000 rows to scan and get the data.

Is there any way i can optimize so it uses less rows to scan and get the data. Also, id is the primary key column.

Comment: This should be a give, but just in case, I need to ask: is there an index on `id`?

Comment: @Max: it's PK, as he specified in the end of the question.

Comment: @zerkms: I could swear that wasn't there when I read it, but there's no revision history. Weird.

Comment: @Max: it was definitely there, because it was there before I start answered.

Comment: yeah, as zerkms mentioned in his answer- why *to retell* what explain have said? Why not to bring the explain output itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> online reference's this is explained as, it took the query 7,500,000 rows to scan and get the data

not actually. it's the **approximate** (optimizer cannot say the correct number in many different cases)  number of rows that **potentially** will be scanned. but you specified `LIMIT` - so only first 16 rows will be affected while query executed.

ps: i hope the used key in EXPLAIN is `id`?

Comment: The used key in EXPLAIN should be `PRIMARY`

Comment: yep. actually it changes nothing. whether key (contains `id` as it leftmost part) is used - this query would be fast.

Answer (score 0):

I performed an explain with your query on a 8 million rows table

```
id   select_type  table       type  possible_keys  key      key_len  ref    rows     Extra
1   SIMPLE       transaction range PRIMARY        PRIMARY  8        NULL   4079100  Using where
```

The actual execution was fast, Execution Time : 00:00:00:044.

Comment: Its not about time, but about the no. of rows it read to get the data. that's the only concern.